# Iphone application fonts

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to find a good font for my Iphone application. I need to use this font in the image below [image]

I just saw this link http://iosfonts.com/ but the font is not available here.

How can I use like same font or any custom font I want?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can import font files (.otf and .ttf) just like you would drag in images to your Xcode project. In the `info.plist` file, add `Fonts provided by application`, which is an array, and add the file name of your font. Then, use the `[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:15]` method.  You can use this website to detect what font is being displayed in that app: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: You also need to add the font to the info.plist for the app. Also bear in mind there is a small loading time for each font on app startup